# How to Logout the App when Refresh the page ? In Django

Tags: python, django

**This Is My code of login in Django Application**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,logout,login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from SedHelper.settings import LOGIN_URL
from .models import HelperApps
# Create your views here.

def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if  request.user.is_authenticated:
            logout(request)
        return render(request,'login.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request,'login.html',context=error)
            # No backend authenticated the credentials
def logout_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    if  request.user.is_authenticated:
        logout(request)
     return redirect(Login)

def home(request):
    #load all data from db(10)
    if  request.user.is_authenticated:
         posts=HelperApps.objects.all()[:11]
         return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'posts':posts})
    else:return redirect(Login)
```

I just wanted to Logout when ever someone refresh the Page .In entire Application where ever someone refresh the the page it should logout immidiately.Anyone please.
i am also new to stackoverflow Please try to ignore the mistakes.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between a refresh and a normal request? Why exactly do you want this feature?

Comment: Use  Django  sessions

Comment: If someone Logs in and uses dashboard and after that he refresh the page then should be Logged Out.

Comment: @BiswajitPaloi Can you Explain How?

Comment: @jaykishan and what if the user just navigates to another page?

Comment: @IainShelvington No not logout on redirect only logout if refresh the page or use direct url of another page.You can check IRCTC Website.They do the same

Answer (score 1):

Create a Middleware, and write this function:

```
def logout_when_refresh(request):
    logout(request)
```

Comment: Can you please Elaborate your answer ?

Comment: In your app dir, create middleware.py, place the above code, then add the middleware you created in MIDDLEWARE in settings.py.